# Read folder created on local machine by using Math.random() method in Node js / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I am trying to read a JSON File which is in folder within a folder and in another folder and this file is created on my local machine while performing some task but the problem is every time folder name get change as folder name is generated by `Math.random()` method but with prefix of `_createdFolder_` so its look like this `_createdFolder_012` in place of `012` it can be `454` or `782` or any number as it is generate by `Math.random()` method if the folder name is fixed I can easily read the file but file name get changed and its been hard to read

and I want to read a json file which is path look like this

folderPath

```
_createdFolder_563/data/systemCode/access.json
```

as I want to read and fetch json file which is created on my local machine while performing some task but if the folder name is fixed I can easily read it but due to `Math.random()` its hard to read a file

```
fs.readFile("_createdFolder_501/data/systemCode/access.json", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
   
    const JsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      
    console.log(JsonData);  
});
```

is there any possible way I can read the folder which is created by `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Meet [FS.readdir(path)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback). It lists the contents of a directory.

You will need to invoke that, giving it the path to the folder that contains the randomly-named folder. That will give you a list of all the files and folders.

Then you need to search that list for an item whose name matches that pattern. Then you have the name you need, and you can do the rest of your logic.

Comment: Hi @Tom I know how Fs.readDir() works but the problem is the place it get downloaded there are n no. of directories and it is really a time consuming to read all the files which is unnecessary

Comment: 1. I think you misunderstand. You are not actually reading the files, you are getting a directory listing for a single directory. That will be practically instantaneous on almost any hardware unless the storage device is a network drive or something. Prove me wrong by posting performance numbers of the `readdir`. 2. Regardless of how long it takes, this is the only way to do it. Whatever program is generating the random directory name, you have no insight into it. So you will have to get the list of items and then study the names to find the right item. And you may need to `stat()` the item.

Comment: ok so you mean `fs.readdir(process.cwd(), (err, files) => {if (err) console.log(err);
 else {
console.log(files);
}
})` I should write this but how will I get `_createdFolder_294` or any `_createdFolder_` from list

Comment: Basically, yes. `files` will be an array of strings. You search that array (using standard Array methods) for an item that matches the naming pattern used by the app.

Comment: so what will be the next step is it like `if( files.includes("_createdFolder_"){ what will be next step }`